# When a span element contains no text, fill with placeholder text

Tags: jquery, css, input

After a great answer I see this might be a possible duplicate of [Placeholder in contenteditable - focus event issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093424/placeholder-in-contenteditable-focus-event-issue)

I have an HTML `<span>` element with the `contenteditable="true"`. My goal is to have a seamless 'input' field utilizing the span element. I'm having issues getting the following flow to work:

- The DOM loads with `<span>` editable and default text of 'Make a new tag ..'
- When User clicks on the `<span>` the text updates to say 'Begin typing ..'
- On first keypress, remove `<span>` text and begin filling with User input
- If the `<span>` has no text and the user is still editing, replace text with 'Begin typing ..'
- If the `<span>` has no text and the user is not interacting, replace text with 'Make a new tag ..'

It works except that when the User is editing the element and they clear all text, the element collapses and becomes uneditable. I need to make sure there is always text inside the `<span>` or I need to find another method of handling these cases

Here is the element I am working with:
*Note: I am using jQuery, Bootstrap, and FontAwesome

```
<span class="badge"><span contenteditable="true" id="new-tag" class="badge alert-info">Make a new tag ..</span><i class="fa fa-lg fa-plus-circle"></i></span>
```

And my javascript:

```
$('#new-tag').click(function(){
    if( $(this).data('editing') !== 'active'){
        $(this).text('Start typing ..');
    }
});

// i do it this way because when .text('') is used, the <span> breaks
$('#new-tag').keydown(function(e){
    if( $(this).data('editing') !== 'active'){
        $(this).text(String.fromCharCode(e.charCode));
    }
    $(this).data('editing','active');
});

$('#new-tag').change(function(){
    if( $(this).data('editing') == 'active' && $(this).text() == ''){
        $(this).text('Make a new tag ..');
        $(this).removeData('editing');
    }
});
```

Can someone make this magic happen? [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwmoehsc/) of what I have posted.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'd suggest that you could consider using CSS:

```
span.badge[contenteditable] {
    display: inline-block;
}
span.badge[contenteditable]:empty::before {
    content: 'Make a new tag';
    display: inline-block;
}
span.badge[contenteditable]:empty:focus::before {
    content: 'Start typing';
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rwmoehsc/3/).

And to make it more customisable, given the `data-*` attributes in the HTML:

```
<span class="badge">
    <span contenteditable="true" id="new-tag" class="badge alert-info" data-placeholder="Make a new tag" data-focused-advice="Start typing"></span><i class="fa fa-lg fa-plus-circle"></i>
</span>
```

The following CSS will use those custom attributes to place the appropriate text:

```
span.badge[contenteditable] {
    display: inline-block;
}
span.badge[contenteditable]:empty::before {
    content: attr(data-placeholder);
    display: inline-block;
}
span.badge[contenteditable]:empty:focus::before {
    content: attr(data-focused-advice);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rwmoehsc/4/).

References:

- Compatibility:

  - [CSS generated content (`::before`/`::after`)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent).
  - [`:empty` (and other 'CSS 3' selectors)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3).
- CSS:

  - [`:empty`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#empty-pseudo).
  - [Generated content, automatic numbering and lists](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html).

Comment: Very clean solution! Wow

Comment: Nevermind, I'm dumb and didn't update the element. Only the CSS. Your answer is flawless. Hah

Comment: Right. The selector for the 'Start typing..' includes the selector `:empty`. This selector requires that there *be no elements, text or white-space*. Therefore it can't match, since you (for some reason) seem to have hard-coded the 'Make a new tag' text in the HTML. You can either remove the `:empty` selector from the CSS, or you can use the approach I showed in my answer that doesn't require, or want, any content in the `[contenteditable]` span.

Comment: Works like a charm! I just changed the color of the text of the two `::before` to emulate the normal placeholder.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/rwmoehsc/2/

Add this css:

```
#new-tag {
   min-width: 150px;
   display: block;
   min-height: 20px;
}
```

Edit: I do not lose the ability to edit the element in FF 33

Edit 2: Nor in chrome 38

Comment: If you edit the element and press ctrl+a and backspace to clear everything, in chrome, it collapses and becomes inactive. Does the same happen to you?

Comment: Oh, interesting. Yes, I was just clicking it and typing, which doesn't cause this behavior.