# How to highlight a contentEditable span on glyphicon click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 spans

```
<span contentEditable=true class="editspan"></span>
<span class="pencilspan glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pull-right"></span>
```

and a js function

```
$(document).on('click', '.pencilspan', function () {
    console.log("clicked pencil");
});
```

What I want is when I click on pencilspan the contentEditable area of editspan should get highlighted(input box should be visible). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at the addClass jQuery function.

Comment: show the html code where u used input

Comment: I dont want to use the input tag to add an input box to editspan. I already have the contentEditable=true flag which gives me an input box automatcially. I just want to highlight the contentEditable areaa or force click on edit span. I tried `$('.editspan').click();
` inside my pencilspan onlick function but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `focus()` method :

```
$(document).on('click', '.pencilspan', function () {
    $(this).siblings('.editspan').focus();
});
```

For empty span issue you can follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26960417/when-a-span-element-contains-no-text-fill-with-placeholder-text)

Comment: I dont want to use the input tag to add an input box to editspan. I already have the contentEditable=true flag which gives me an input box automatcially. I just want to highlight the contentEditable areaa or force click on edit span. I tried `$('.editspan').click();
` inside my pencilspan onlick function but it did not work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is almost working the only issue is if I dont have any text inside span this doesnt work and if I have anything inside span it works. `<span contentEditable=true class="editspan">text</span>` works but `<span contentEditable=true class="editspan"></span>` does not work

Comment: @lovesoftlayeraj I have added a link in the answer please check it.

Comment: Looks good though there is still a small issue. These span elements are in a table column. All cells in one of the columns has these spans. and I noticed that whichever pencil icon I click it focuses the edtispan in the first row's column only. Any idea why this behaviour? I want that whichever row's pencil icon I click only that row's editspan column must be focussed

Answer (score 0):

Please try this might help you if you are looking for toggle:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.editInput{
display:none;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<span contentEditable=true class="editspan">
<input type = 'text' value ='' class='editInput' />
</span>
<span class="pencilspan glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pull-right">button</span>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '.pencilspan', function () {
   // var editInput = "<input type = 'text' value ='' />";
    $('.editspan .editInput').toggle();

});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I dont want to use the input tag to add an input box to editspan. I already have the contentEditable=true flag which gives me an input box automatcially. I just want to highlight the contentEditable areaa or force click on edit span. I tried `$('.editspan').click();
` inside my pencilspan onlick function but it did not work.

Comment: @lovesoftlayeraj: please try this

$(document).on('click', '.pencilspan', function () {
   $('.editspan input').focus();

});