# Placeholder for contenteditable div with minimal JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a `div` tag with the `contenteditable` attribute.
I want to put the placeholder in here, and I found the following code.

```css
[contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  display: block;
  /* For Firefox */
}
```

```html
<div class="test" contenteditable="true" placeholder="test"></div>
```

In a chromium-based engine, it looks like it's working. But I heard there is an error here that requires JavaScript. I couldn't find the error. Can you tell me what the problem is?

I'm also not sure that `content:attr();` is the web standard in css. Is it a standardized CSS property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that a `<br>` is automatically inserted inside a `contenteditable div` when it is empty. I think that they added `<br>` to prevent it from collapsing. Here's where they discussed this: [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1098151).

Here's an example of the collapse prevention I mentioned. You can see that, initially, `div` has 0 height. However, you can still focus on it. Try typing, then erasing everything. Browser automatically inserts `<br>` to prevent it from returning to 0 height by adding a `<br>` which is one line-height high.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Test"></div>
```

So we can simply use `<span>`, which does not insert a random `<br>`, instead of `<div>` to do what you want like so. Try typing, then erasing the characters. The placeholder will be there exactly as you want it to be.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

span {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: text;
}

span:empty::before {
  content: attr(data-placeholder);
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  color: #00000066;
}
```

```html
<span contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Test"></span>
```

If you really have to use `div`, then you can erase the `<br>` manually using JS:

```js
const editable = document.querySelector('#editable')
editable.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  if (editable.innerText === '\n') editable.innerHTML = ''
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#editable {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: text;
}

div:empty::before {
  content: attr(data-placeholder);
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  color: #00000066;
}
```

```html
<div id="editable" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Test"></div>
```

Using `attr()` function in CSS with `content` is not experimental. With other CSS properties like `color`, though, it is still experimental. Read further on this [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr).

Comment: @eujin That's a different question for a different problem. I recommend asking a new question.

Comment: I'll get it organized. Thank you very much for your kind reply.

Comment: @eujin If you found my answer helpful, please do consider accepting my answer ;-)

Answer (score 3):

In .html

```
<div placeholder="Write your message.." contenteditable class="form-control edit-box holder"></div>
```

In .css

```
.holder:before {
    content: attr(placeholder);
    color: lightgray;
    display: block;
    position:absolute;    
    font-family: "Campton", sans-serif;
}
```

This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It works on Firefox too. I think I found the "error" that may require the supposed Javascript. Try typing in the div, then delete all of it by CTRL+A backspace; the placeholder won't come back because there's a `<br>` the browser has automatically inserted (`<p></p>` in other browsers).

The `content` property and `attr(...)` has been standard since IE8, so it's fine.

Comment: I found the answer you copied on the link. It looks like all of the CSS-only solutions has this issue. Answer #2 at the link (which is CSS only) has a comment that says `this fails and is unreliable`. So try out the first solution (even if it looks ugly).

Comment: Now I finally found what to do. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Jon.Frenchtoast The first solution has a problem too. Try focusing on the div, then direct the focus elsewhere. The placeholder will be missing.

Comment: @Richard I found out it doesn't even work when you actually type something and then refocus on it, it deletes it. I don't think any of the solutions there work *exactly* like how the `placeholder` attribute is specified in HTML5.

Comment: Thank you for your sound discussion. When I clicked somewhere else, I noticed the problem of the focus. What do you think of this link? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20726174/placeholder-for-contenteditable-div) , [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093424/placeholder-in-contenteditable-focus-event-issue)